# How to Display, Local System Date Format in RDLC Field

Tags: c#, .net, windows, rdlc, date-format

**Hi**

**Please Help**

I Have `RDLC` Report, in that i have `TransactionDate`(which displays in the format of `5/25/2017`) and my Local system date format is `25-05-2017`.
Now i want to display, that `RDLC` Field (`TransactionDate`) should be same as `Local System Date`.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want your date time in this format < Day-Month-Year >
Well it's simple

```
        DateTime a = new DateTime();
        string localDate = a.Day + "-" + a.Month + "-" +a.Year;
```

And if you just want to edit current Date you got:

```
        string input = "25/5/2017"; //Get your input how you want
        string[] a = input.Split('/');
        string output = a[0] + "-" + a[1] + "-" + a[2];
```

Comment: no, i don't want to hard-code my date format,i want to display a system format a same as in rdlc report field.(that is, if my system format is dd-MM-yyyy then i want to display in my rdlc report as same as dd-MM-yyyy)

Answer (score 2):

Select the textbook in rdlc and press f4 , there you can find the format properties, there you can directly define the format like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set the locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/set-the-locale-for-a-report-or-text-box-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017) in an RDLC file, either

- for the whole report, by modifying the Report's `Language` property, or
- for a single text box, by modifying the text box's `Language` property.

For example, setting `Language` to `en-IN` will cause a date to be formatted as `25-05-2017` instead of `5/25/2017`. Setting it to the expression `=User!Language` will cause the RDLC engine to use the current thread's locale.